# Crossover design

Tags: audio

I have just built a really simple amplifier based on an LM386:

[image: Circuit diagram of amplifier]

And I am now looking to design a crossover to go with it.  What is the most appropriate type of crossover design to use here?  I am looking at driving two 8Ω speakers; a [tweeter](http://www.jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=CT2007) and a [midrange/woofer](http://www.jaycar.com.au/productView.asp?ID=CW2190).  I don't need anything really fancy, just a basic inductor/capacitor low/high pass filter.

EDIT: Please look at the links for specifics on my speakers!

EDIT: I would also like to know; What kind of capacitor should one use for the high capacitance values required by an audio crossover? I have been yet unable to find any that are suitable.

Comment: The 1st part of the question about the design of crossover is okay.  The 2nd part is about sourcing, so it's off-topic on the EE.SE board.  I took a liberty to edit the 2nd part out.  If you still need to talk about sourcing, you can ask sourcing question in the [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Comment: Have you considered an active crossover? - i.e build a second amp to handle the second speaker and split the common input audio signal with a simple RC network (one high pass, one low low pass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cross over needs to seperate bands of frequencies so that you are not wasting power feeding bass to a tweater and possibly damaging it. Firstly the bass crossover. I've chosen a cross over frequency of 500Hz but this needs to be considered in light of the speakers you wish to use. I've gone to [this](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/RLCtool.php) website and plugged some numbers in to the online calculator: -

[image]

The R in the circuit I've chosen to be the impedance of the speaker (8 ohms) although strictly speaking I should check to see that it is largely 8 ohms resistive at bass/middle. I've used 30uF and 3.3mH for the cap and inductor and this gives a 3dB cross over at 505Hz with a damping ratio of about 0.7.

See the graphs for predicted overshoot and passband - overshoot is about 1.07 (7%) and there will be an almost unnoticable peak in the spectrum. At 1kHz the signal level will be reduced by about 12dB. It is performing as a low pass filter.

The nice Mr. Okawa (the site I used) has got a similar page for a high pass filter using a series C and L//R down to ground - you should be able to follow the link and have a go yourself.